# Spring security with filter-mapping - Filter not called with dispather tags

Tags: java, spring-security

I am using spring security and also adding a filter mapping as below.

My spring security configurations are:

```
<http entry-point-ref="httpAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" method="OPTIONS" access="true"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <form-login 
        authentication-success-handler-ref="authSuccessHandler"
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="authFailureHandler"/>
    <logout success-handler-ref="httpLogoutSuccessHandler"/>
    <custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="sessionContextFilter" />
</http>
```

And the filter-mapping defined in the web-fragment is:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>customFilter</filter-name>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

The issue is that, "customFilter" is not being called in the login/logout request. If I add the url-pattern like below, then its being called

```
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

Any idea why its not working without the url-pattern?

PS: I can not merge the "customFilter" with the spring configurations as the spring-configuration can be overwritten and I dont want them to add my custom filter which is not related to security.

Answer (score 0):

According to web.xml deployment descriptor [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1039330) a `<filter-mapping>` element must have either `<url-pattern>` or `<servlet-name>` element. You are omitting both that is why it is not working

Comment: but the strange part is that its being called for the other requests. The problem is just with Login/Logout request.